# How do I instantiate an instance of a class in Python?

Tags: python, import, pycharm

I'm new to python and doing some practice for uni,

I'm familiar with java so I am trying to create a class in python and then create an instance of the class to be used as an object from another file in the same directory.

so here's how I'm trying to do it:

within main.py -

```
import player
p1 = player.Player(300, 300, 64, 64)
```

here's my Player class located in player.py

```
import main
class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 15
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.walkCount = 0
```

this results in:

AttributeError: module 'player' has no attribute 'Player'

After some research I have also tried:

```
from player import Player
p1 = Player(300, 300, 64, 64)
```

which results in: ImportError: cannot import name 'Player' from 'player' (C:\Users\Alex\PycharmProjects\BunkerGame\player.py)

quite simply and ignoring some other code this should create an instance of the Player class in player.py to be used within the main.py file

Comment: What is the "other code"? Could you have a circular import somewhere?

Comment: But note, your question is about importing, not instantiating.

Comment: The code you posted, works fine.

Comment: I import main in player.py: import main

Comment: @Alex: Do you execute/run the script through PyCharm ?

Comment: yes and both files are definitely in the same directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted in the comment, you import main into player - which means you have a circular import: Python can't resolve this so raises an attribute error.

You shouldn't need to do that. There shouldn't be anything in main that is needed by player. If there is, move it to player itself or a third module.

Comment: If he indeed imported `main.py` from `player.py`, this is indeed correct. +1

Answer (score 1):

From the error you mentioned you most likely have a module already installed called `player`, which Python is importing as opposed to your local file `player.py`. Try renaming the file `player.py` to something else, or going on console and doing `pip uninstall player`.

Notice how the error says `cannot import name 'Player' from 'player'`, which means Python is accessing a module called `player`, but is unable to access the class `Player`.

Comment: Both scripts are being imported on to each other. import player on main and import main on player

Answer (score 1):

As @Daniel Roseman pointed out, I had 'import main' within player.py which python doesn't like apparently, removing this and any related code fixed the issue!

Comment: but I still need to use variable from main.py!! I'll do some more research

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Try decoupling your code and ensuring that `main.py` only **passes** variables to other functions -- do access variables directly from `main.py` from other files.

Answer (score 0):

You just should write the import just like this:

```
import Player

p1 = Player(300, 300, 64, 64)
```

You can also write something like:

```
import Player as p

p1 = p(300, 300, 64, 64)
```

Comment: well doing this exactly results in "no module named Player", my file name is player and the class within is Player, do you mean: import player     p1 = player.Player(300, 300, 64, 64)? this throws AttributeError: module 'player' has no attribute 'Player'

Comment: Do you have the files in the same directory? If you do it should work with import [filename]

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the `player.` You are passing a class through as an attribute by using `.` which is the reason for the first error and the second is that your importing main on your player page and importing player on your main page. Just get rid of `import main` on your player page.

The first error:

```
import player

p1 = player.Player(300, 300, 64, 64)
```

This should just be:

```
import player

p1 = Player(300, 300, 64, 64)
```

Here is an example of whats happened:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

player = Player # setting the class to variable

player.name = 'Johnny' # .name is the attribute of the Player class
print(player.name)
```

Output:

```
'Johnny'
```

You have done this:

```
player.Player.name = 'Johnny'
print(player.name)
```

Which returns your error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "main.py", 
line 8, in <module>          
player.Player.name = 'Johnny'AttributeError: type object 'Player' has no attribute 'Player'
```

Comment: This is incorrect. He is importing the module named `player` in the example you listed, and then calling the class named `Player` within that module. Therefore `player.Player` is in fact correct. The code you listed above would be wrong. This is the equivalent of doing `import math` and assuming Python would know that `sqrt(4)` is equivalent to `math.sqrt(4)` -- `sqrt(4)` would return the error `name 'sqrt' is not defined`, where `math.sqrt(4)` would work.

Comment: I have added the proof and error in the answer for you.